# Replicating iOS 5 Stocks Widget

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

Anyone have any ideas on how I could go about replicating the scrolling stocks ticker in Notification Center on iOS 5?

What I'm thinking is using a `UIScrollView`, and use a `UIView` subclass for the items in the ticker. Would using an `NSTimer` be the best way to have it scroll automatically? How would I handle manual scrolling acceleration and deceleration like the Apple stocks widget does?

Also, how do I handle infinite scrolling?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Possibly this github repository, I haven't checked it out, so Ill post This as an answer if it is satisfactory: https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKTickerViewDemo

Comment: @CodaFi I've actually tried that. It kind of works, but handles acceleration and deceleration very poorly if even at all.

Comment: Hmm... Maybe a UIPageViewController set in an infinite loop?

Answer (score 1):

Try [AutoScrollLabel](https://github.com/cbess/AutoScrollLabel). It's a relatively old class, but the code design and animation behind it may be useful. If I understand correctly, it's a `UIScrollView` that holds two labels, each saying the same thing, resulting in "scrolling" as it animates between them. I'm sure you could take that concept and the `drawRect:` method in the code to create your own subclass of the `UIScrollView` and animate whatever content you want, complete with infinite scrolling. There may very well be an easier way, but I've used AutoScrollLabel in a few apps and it's easy to use and works without a problem. Let me know if you need more info/a usage example. Hope this helps!